# Sweep and Prune: where does temporal coherence come in?

Tags: collision-detection

I am researching various collision detection algorithms, one of them being sweep and prune. I think I have a good understanding of how it works; you store a sorted list of endpoints for each axis and during each update I have to keep the list sorted. Below is the link to one of the web pages I've found that helped me understand this algorithm:

http://jitter-physics.com/wordpress/?tag=sweep-and-prune

However, I'm not too clear about how temporal coherence is being implemented in the code. I understand that it takes advantage of the fact that objects move very little in consecutive time frames, but I don't quite see how it can be implemented.

Can someone shed some light onto this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I may have found the answer to my own question. Temporal coherence merely reduces the amount of work to be done for narrow phase collision detection. I was examining the code in the below link.

http://www.koders.com/java/fidB3D3D9D154CE69A671A799D52E7C44C104DF9537.aspx?s=w.a

I think this is where temporal coherence comes into play: when an object pair is considered for collision and it goes into narrow phase collision, the array of endpoints will be sorted. Until the endpoints need to be sorted again, there is no need to look for object pairs to be considered for narrow phase collision because the if statement at line 76 will never be true. If that's the case, then the code follows the principle of temporal coherence: in small time steps, the object configurations will change so little that it will not warrant an array sort; nothing will be rearranged in the array. Therefore the amount of narrow phase collision will be reduced.

Answer (score 3):

+1 for the question, but your answer is perhaps wrong; temporal coherence is exploited between one simulation step to the next, at the sort (sweep) phase. Here's an excerpt from Wikipedia's [Sweep and Prune](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_and_prune):

> Sweep and prune exploits temporal coherence as it is likely that solids do not move significantly between two simulation steps. Because of that, at each step, the sorted lists of bounding volume starts and ends can be updated with relatively few computational operations. Sorting algorithms which are fast at sorting almost-sorted lists, such as insertion sort, are particularly good for this purpose.

Say we've *n* objects, at time step 1, *t = 1*, for the sweep phase, we've sorted all the object's `start.x` and `end.x` and based on the results, we've performed the narrow phase too to find the actual colliding objects. Now, for *t = 2*, unless your simulation has objects that could teleport (disappear and reappear elsewhere), the objects would move slightly from their *t = 1* position, at *t = 2*. Between *t = 1* and *2*, if the change in `X` isn't much (temporal coherence), then the sorted list we created for *t = 1* will generally give a good head start for arriving at the sorted list of *t = 2* since for *t = 2* the older list is so close to perfectly-sorted state. Now, by using some sort like [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort), which may be costly for the general case but will work well in this almost-sorted case, one can quickly get to the perfectly sorted list for *t = 2*.